# Write output to csv from nested loop?

Tags: python, csv

I have several loops within a larger loop, and I need the csv file to be written to twice:

**UPDATED, more detailed example**

```
with open("file.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8", newline="") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    while True:
        try:
            element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
            if element.is_displayed():
                nextbtn=driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
                object=driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
                writer.writerows(object)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            urls=driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)
            urls= [url.get_attribute('href') for url in urls]

            for url in urls:
                driver.get(url)
                object = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
                writer.writerows(object)
```

Essentially what the code is doing is testing to check if an element is present. If the element is present, the next button is clicked. Once the next button is clicked, a specific element, `object`, is scraped and written to csv.

If the certain element is not present, the code then collects a list of urls, and for each url, it scrapes the element `object` and prints it to csv.

Regardless of which page is navigated to, I want the object element. However, the problem lies in writing to csv, as the results from `try` are not being written to the csv. Although the location of `object` is the same for both pages, the value of `object` is different, depending on the page.

How would I rewrite this code such that both results are written in the same .csv?

Comment: So you want to write the content that is in the if and the else?

Comment: Yes! But the reason that the ```write.writerow(element)``` cannot be outside of the if/else is that within the if/else I navigate to different pages.

Comment: If one path of an if is taken, the other will not be taken. You can use two if statements instead of an else, and have both statements be valid for the case you are checking.

Comment: Yes, it is fine that if one path is taken that one is not; it doesn't matter which path it takes (I'm essentially navigating to different pages). But as long as the correct element is writing to csv, that's the goal.

Comment: Where is `element_exists` determined? Where is `element` determined?

Comment: _Right now, the results from else are overwriting the results from if element_exists._ What, how can they be overwriting each other? Aren't you writing the same thing anyway?

Comment: @AMC my apologies, I tried to keep things as simple as possible, but I've inadvertently made it confusing. I've updated the example. Please let me know if it makes sense now

Comment: @jpf I've updated the post, please let me know if it is not clear

Comment: I'm still confused by the use of the word "overwrite", might there be a different term which would make things clearer?

Comment: @AMC the results from the try loop are not being written to csv. I had thought that meant they were being overwritten, but perhaps not then. Does that make things clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else that runs into the same issue, the problem was NOT the syntax writing to .csv. To write to a .csv in a nested loop, the syntax I posted above is correct.

The issue in this case was that the element `object` I was trying to find in the `try` loop was not being found, and was therefore writing empty rows, whereas the object was being found in the `except` loop. I used an if/else statement within the `try` to write a cell "element not found" to csv. Alternatively, you could just leave it blank.